# Ionic Problems In Push function

Tags: angular, function, ionic-framework, npm, push

Whenever I try to push the page with passing the data in `ionic` then they give me this error:

> "this.navctrl.push()" not a function

So how can I solve this problem because my work is stopped!

```
dishSelected(dish: any) {
    // That's right, we're pushing to ourselves!
    this.navCtrl.push(DishdetailPage,{
      dish:dish
    });
  }
```

And I get the same problem with `dismiss()` function:

```
dismiss() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }
```

Comment: Which version of Ionic you are using? please do ionic -v

Comment: Please import navCtrl like this: `import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';`
and pass it in constructor: `public navCtrl: NavController`;

Answer (score 0):

check the version of ionic you have , if you are using ionic 4 check [this](https://ionicframework.com/blog/navigating-the-change-with-ionic-4-and-angular-router/)
because it's different that ionic 3 , you can check you ionic version using

```
ionic -v
```

or

`ionic -info`